# Упорядоченный список lock-free

Tags: c++, алгоритм, winapi, списки, lock-free

Есть такой метод вставки элемента в упорядоченный список. Будет-ли он корректен для `lock-free`?

```
template< typename _Pred >
inline void lock_free_push( sll_node*tail, sll_node*n, _Pred Pred ){
    std::list< sll_node* >Local;
    sll_node*head,*next;
    //
    for( Local.push_back( n ) ; !Local.empty() ; ){
        n   = Local.back();
        head    = tail->next;
        if( ( head == tail ) || Pred( n, head ) ){
            n->next = head;
            if( _InterlockedCompareExchangePtr( &tail->next, n, head ) == head ){
                Local.pop_back();
            }
        }else if( head != tail ){
            next    = head->next;
            if( _InterlockedCompareExchangePtr( &tail->next, next, head ) == head ){
                Local.insert(
                    std::find_if(
                        Local.begin(), Local.end(), [ = ]( sll_node*e ){
                            return Pred( head, e );
                        }
                    ), head
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**В двух словах:** здесь происходит рекурсивная вставка локального элемента `n` в голову кольцевого interlocked-списка с пограничным элементом `tail`, при условии, что `n <= head`. Если `n > head`, то производится попытка извлечь головной элемент. Если получается, он размещается в локальном списке `Local`. Итерации продолжаются до тех пор, пока `Local` непустой. **В итоге, из стека `lock-free` мы должны получить упорядоченный список `lock-free`.**

`tail` - хвостовой(головной) пограничный элемент `lock-free`-стека
`sll_node` - узел односвязного списка
`Pred( a, b )` - произвольный метод, возвращающий `TRUE`, если `a <= b`

Можно обойтись и без STL, контейнер взят для упрощения реализации. Кто-нибудь видит ошибки?

**UPD1:** убрал преобразования дабы не ломать строки.
**UPD2:** реализация того же самого, но уже без `STL`:

```
template< typename _Pred >
inline void lock_free_push( sll_node*tail, sll_node*n, _Pred Pred ){
    sll_node**p,*head,*next, local;
    // вставляем в `local` узел `n` и повторяем итерации,
    // пока `local` непустой
    for( n->next = &local, local.next = n ; local.next != &local ; ){
        // берем из `local` максимальный элемент (первый)
        n   = local.next;
        // запоминаем головной элемент стека в `head`
        head    = tail->next;
        if( ( head == tail ) || Pred( n, head ) ){
            // список пуст или `n <= head` - запоминаем локальный хвост, после `n`
            next    = n->next;
            // пытаемся атомарно разместить `n` на вершине стека,
            // если она не изменилась
            n->next = head;
            if( _InterlockedCompareExchangePtr( &tail->next, n, head ) == head ){
                // получилось - удаляем `n` из `local`
                local.next  = next;
            }else{
                // не получилось - восстанавливаем локальный хвост
                // и продолжаем lock-free итерации    
                n->next = next;
            }
        }else if( head != tail ){
            // список не пуст и `n > head` - запоминаем хвост, после `head` в `next`
            // и пытаемся атомарно вытолкнуть вершину стека `head`,
            // если она не изменилась
            next    = head->next;
            if( _InterlockedCompareExchangePtr( &tail->next, next, head ) == head ){
                // получилось - ищем позицию для `head` в `local`:
                // сортировка по убыванию
                for( p = &local.next ; ( *p != &local ) && Pred( head, *p ) ; p = &(*p)->next );
                // размещаем `head` в `local`
                head->next  = *p;
                *p          = head;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В худшем случае - какой-нибудь один поток заберет себе все элементы, упорядочит и вставит их обратно.

**Комментарии:**

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что в процессе часть элементов из списка tail перемещается в local?
>
> Если да, то ведь они (элементы) станут невидимыми для других потоков (а не только для потоков заносящих в список новые элементы).
>
> Это предусмотрено в общем алгоритме обработки данных?

Я пробую использовать такой объект при распределении задач на SMP, т.е. да, подразумевается, что есть другие средства, обеспечивающие поток информацией о том, что существуют другие элементы списка, которые нужно просто "подождать".

Вобщем-то это делается элементарно: просто заводится `interlocked`-счетчик узлов в списке. Если узел удален, счетчик уменьшает значение. Если просто блокирован (эксклюзивно используется в теле потока), счетчик хранит значение об этом узле, не отпуская остальные потоки. Как-то так. :)

> Просто представьте ситуацию с выдачей заданий разным программистам на обработку данных в такой системе.
>
> Одному - получать извне, добавлять и упорядочивать. Он этот lock_free_push() будет вызывать.
>
> Другому - искать в сортированных списках и считать суммы (или еще чего-нибудь).
>
> Вот заказчик удивится, когда увидит, что сумма то растет, то убывает (а по физике процесса может только расти).

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), я подразумеваю здесь работу только в привычной пардигме стека `lock-free`, но с небольшим дополнением, которое может оказаться ключевым: у такого стека с вершины можно снимать "минимальный" элемент. Т.е., конечно, упорядочить можно в любом направлении, но из всех доступных **в данный момент** узлов, с точки зрения алгоритма - минимальный всегда будет на вершине стека.

p.s.: странный все таки регламент на Хэшкоде по поводу комментариев, почему нельзя контролировать их число индивидуально?

Comment: @mega, для начала разъясните *Вашу* терминологию (в основном что такое lock-free?).

Если речь идет о совместной работе потоков со списком, то не могли бы Вы перевести это (в целях обсуждения) на posix threads?

Comment: @avp, здесь нет _моей_ терминологии, это известный [Non-blocking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-free_and_wait-free_algorithms)

Comment: `POSIX` тут воткнуть просто некуда, поскольку тема касается управления потоками только косъвенно. Здесь работа с синхронизацией, построенной на взаимоблокировках. В `POSIX` есть на них стандарт?

Comment: @mega, извините, отстал... Ознакомился с wiki по Вашей ссылке. Про posix можно замять. 

--

Относительно вопроса, не могли бы Вы "разжевать" семантику _InterlockedCompareExchangePtr()?

Что именно делает (и чего не делает) эта функция.

--

Насколько понял есть односвязный список, в его элементах Вы манипулируете указателем `next`. При "внешнем" вызове указатель на первый элемент списка это `tail`, а `n` указатель на вставляемый элемент и у него `next` NULL.

Потоки, вызывающие `lock_free_push()` не синхронизированы, но *всегда* вызывают ее с указателем на первый элемент списка.

Так?

Comment: [InterlockedCompareExchange(( x, y, z ))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560(v=vs.85).aspx) реализует `cmpxchg`, которая сравнивает `*x` c `z` и в случае, если они равны, записывает в `*x` значение `y`. Подробнее можно посмотреть [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_с_обменом).
--
Все правильно, только не важно, что стоит в `n->next` и `tail` - это не первый, а пограничный элемент кольцевого списка - аналог `std::list::end()`. Т.е. `tail->next === std::list::begin()`, а `&tail === std::list::end()`.

Comment: Насчет кольцевого списка я уже понял (после ввода комментария).

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в процессе часть элементов из списка tail перемещается в local?

Если да, то ведь они (элементы) станут невидимыми для других потоков (а не только для потоков заносящих в список новые элементы). 

Это предусмотрено в общем алгоритме обработки данных? 

--

Т.е. что получается с т.з. потока просматривающего список? На первом проходе `X` был, а на следующем его уже в списке нет, а спустя некоторое время опять появился. А ведь говорят только insert...

К такой коллекции программисту надо быть готовым...

Comment: >Правильно ли я понимаю, что в процессе часть элементов из списка tail перемещается в local?

Да, по-моему, здесь это единственный выход.

>они (элементы) станут невидимыми для других потоков.

Похоже, в этом суть подобных алгоритмов, т.е. доступность элемента во времени, которое оперделяется взаимными уступками со стороны участвующих потоков. В общем случае - потоков, закрепленных на своем ядре. А, кстати, где говорится на счет `insert`?

Comment: @mega, непосредственно Вы про insert ничего не говорили.

--

Просто представьте ситуацию с выдачей заданий разным программистам на обработку данных в такой системе. 

Одному - получать извне, добавлять и упорядочивать. Он этот lock_free_push() будет вызывать.

Другому - искать в сортированных списках и считать суммы (или еще чего-нибудь).

Вот заказчик удивится, когда увидит, что сумма то растет, то убывает (а по физике процесса может только расти).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А какая принципиальная разница между AVL и красно-черными? Думаю для практики все равно.

Результат, конечно может быть одним, но для меня проще явно вести учет разности высот поддеревьев. На мой взгляд, именно этот подход максимально раскрывает суть алгоритма балансировки.

> Интересно другое. Когда можно (нужно) применять lock-free алгоритмы к достаточно сложным структурам?

К достаточно сложным - не уверен.

> Видимо только в случаях, когда одновременный доступ маловероятен.

Вот именно это мне сейчас и интересно.

Имеется **N** потоков и одна параллельная задача. Задача решается итерациями. Каждая итерация выполняется примерно фиксированное время (регулировка длительности итерации [дискретизации задачи] производится извне, статично). Каждый поток, выполняет свою итерацию. А поскольку, изначально задача одна, следовательно ее нужно разделить на оставшиеся потоки. Пусть каждый поток, которому не досталось задачи берет задачу с максимальным ресурсом и делит ее на два. Если поток решил свою итерацию, он ищет новую свободную задачу или пытается разделить максимальную, если число задач меньше числа потоков. Задача считается доступной для деления, если ее размер выше заданного предела. Таким образом, пока задача делится, потоки всегда будут заняты ее решением.

Вот такой алгоритм я пробую реализовать без блокировок. Список - это список свободных задач. Задачи, которые на данный момент не взял на себя ни один поток. Свободную задачу можно либо разделить, либо решить одну из ее итераций. Естественно, число задач не должно превышать число потоков, но могут быть небольшие логичные исключения. Поскольку число потоков равно числу ядер, то список достаточно мал, чтобы сильно заморачиваться на сортировке, но возможно над оптимизацией сортировки придется задуматься, если будет большая конкуренция между потоками.

Теоретически, я могу посчитать время, потраченное на конкуренцию между потоками на взаимоблокировках, т.к. я могу "очень дешево" посчитать число итераций холостых циклов и могу примерно посчитать, сколько тактов выполняются сами циклы.

Т.е., в конечном счете, это будет процент времени, потраченный на совокупную синхронизацию lock-free.

Не могу только посчитать время, потраченное на синхронизацию стандартными средствами ( критические секции, мьютексы ). Если явно расставлять замеры тактов перед такими блокировками, оно будет весьма неточное. Похоже, самым логичным способом будет замерить время выполнения задачи на обоих видах синхронизации и определить, дает ли выигрыш lock-free в данном случае. Но такими экспериментами я если и буду заниматься, то нескоро, т.к. ограничен свободным временем.

**Update:** честно говоря, на `SMP` мне так и не удалось стабилизировать этот алгоритм.

Но после долгого и упорного исследования `lock-free` пришел к выводу, что в чистом виде (`inline`) такие методы неработоспособны. Для дальнейших экспериментов их нужно **нафаршировать барьерными синхронизациями** как на уровне компилятора `_ReadBarrier/_WriteBarrier/_ReadWriteBarrier`, так и на уровне аппаратуры `_mm_lfence/_mm_sfence/_mm_mfence`.

Буду очень благодарен, если найдутся рабочие примеры именно с такой организацией очереди задач, поскольку, у меня все же есть вполне конкретные ожидания на счет `lock-free`:

Я запускал тестовую задачу "отсечение набора точек прямоугольным окном". Каждая из итераций этой задачи считает время, потраченное на решение и накапливает его в аккумуляторе ядра ( потоке, закрепленном на ядре ). После завершения расчетов, расчитывается ключевой параметр - число точек в секунду, равный `S / T`, где `T` - это суммарное время работы всех итераций на самом медленном ядре( потоке, закрепленном на ядре ), а `S` - общее число обработанных точек. В случае с `lock-free` эта характеристика однажды разогналась до 300 млн. в сек. на восьми 3GHz-ядрах. хотелось бы мне такую скорость и оставить взамен 20-50 млн. с блокировками.

Причем "разогналась" - это именно то слово, поскольку я запускал эту задачу в цикле 100 раз, и на каждой последующей итерации получал прирост показателя скорости.

> на SMP мне так и не удалось стабилизировать этот алгоритм.

Где-то с месяц назад у меня все таки получилась такая реализация. Причем сразу в 3-х вариантах: на [Interlocked Singly Linked Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683648(v=vs.85).aspx), на динамическом стеке (когда число задач непредсказуемо растет) и на статическом стеке (когда максимальное число задач заранее известно, либо есть возможность использовать фиксированный пул задач).

Производительность на `API` ниже, поскольку тратим время на вызов функции и не имеем возможности сортировать вершины.

Производительность на статическом стеке самая максимальная. Хотя своя реализация `lock-free-стека` без `SIMD`-расширения не обошлась. Сейчас точно не скажу конкретные цифры, но **моя предварительная оценка** задействованию такой сортировки - это `~3-6%` выигрыш по сравнению с базовым алгоритмом `lock-free`, `~20-30%` - по сравнению со "спином", а на "ядерных" объектах синхронизации я даже не считал (здесь сравнить сложнее, т.к. реализация планировщика на них будет заметно отличаться от `lock-free`).

Более подробно опишу реализацию в отдельном топике, немного позднее, когда будет время на простенький тест.

Comment: @mega, мне вообще нравятся такие исследования. С удовольствием плюсую.

Comment: см. обновление ответа.

Comment: @mega, прочитал обновление. К сожалению ничего конкретного (в тему) у меня нет.

Я обычно делаю очередь через sem_t (использую sem_wait(), sem_post())  для пула потоков (pthreads) (все в линуксе). Обычно скорость ограничивается приходом соединений по сети. Для коротких соединений на 8-CPU получается около 30 тыс. в секунду.

Просто распараллеливанием вычислений (локальной обработкой) не занимался.

Answer (score 0):

[@mega](/users/8766/mega), по поводу регламента **абсолютно** согласен, но изменить это вряд ли удастся. Вот у меня комментарии кончились и пришлось начать "ответ". Совсем неприятно то, что информация об **обновлении** вопроса (вот Вы его обновили) и видимо ответа не отсылается по почте. Я просто обратил внимание на "подъем" Вашего вопроса в общем списке.

По делу. Я так и не уверен, что правильно понимаю Ваши структуры данных. В частности не понимаю, почему вы говорите о **стеке** (в моем понимании стек это FIFO). Я вижу их так:

1. Есть циклический односвязный список, упорядоченный по возрастанию.
2. При вызове lock_free_push() `tail` указывает на произвольный элемент в нем.
3. Целью вызова является вставка нового элемента с сохранением упорядоченности списка.
4. Много потоков одновременно выполняют данную операцию без использования "мьютексов".
5. Для любого другого (не вызвавшего lock_free_push() потока текущий состав списка не имеет значения, но список остается упорядоченным.

Так?

Если да, то мне непонятно, как обеспечивается корректность всех "tail" в потоках, не участвующих в вызове lock_free_push(), если только это не "глобальный" для каждого списка указатель. Возможно именно в этом и дело. Т.е. для каждый список представлен ровно одной переменной, указывающей на элемент этого списка (минимальный) и эта переменная разделяется всеми потоками использующими список. Это предположение 2.

Какое верное?

Не знаю, конечно, общей цели Вашей задачи в SMP системе, но в ядре Linux для структур с быстрым доступом к минимальному элементу используют красно-черное дерево.

Comment: >Так?

Да, так. Но это опять же не _мои_ структуры. Это простой кольцевой список, с пограничным элементом, который я просто адаптировал для работы с алгоритмом `lock-free`. В 5 можно дополнить: помимо `push` есть `pop`:

 inline sll_node*lock_free_pop( sll_node*tail ){
  sll_node*head,*next;
loop:
  head = tail->next;
  next = head->next;
  if( _InterlockedCompareExchangePtr( &tail->next, next, head ) != head ){
   goto loop;
  }
  return head;
 }
который вызывают потоки, работающие со стеком (это классический lock-free pop).

Comment: Т.е. если требуется блокировать элемент в потоке, мы вызываем `pop` и работаем с узлом эксклюзивно. Если мы хотим вернуть узел в `shared`-стек, мы вызываем `push`. Я лишь хотел сделать автоматическую сортировку такого стека, чтобы убить 2-х зайцев.

>Если да, то мне непонятно, как обеспечивается корректность всех "tail" в потоках, не участвующих в вызове lock_free_push(), если только это не "глобальный" для каждого списка указатель.

`tail` - это указатель на пограничный элемент списка и он один, т.к. список тоже один. Если Вы это и имели ввиду, то да, `tail` во всех потоках имеет один адрес.

Comment: >Т.е. для каждый список представлен ровно одной переменной, указывающей на элемент этого списка (минимальный) и эта переменная разделяется всеми потоками использующими список. Это предположение 2

Этого я не понял, поэтому сейчас не могу ответить.

>в ядре Linux для структур с быстрым доступом к минимальному элементу используют красно-черное дерево

Можете развить эту мысль? В смысле, я знаю что такое красно-черное дерево, но я не понял контекста его использования.

Comment: @mega, теперь понял, кстати, "передположение 2" как раз соответствует Вашему:

    tail - это указатель на пограничный элемент списка и он один, т.к. список тоже один.

Контекст красно-черного дерева - скорость работы. Естественно, там (в ядре) это на относится к lock-free алгоритмам. 

--

Навскидку даже не могу представить, с какой скоростью будет работать 
lock_free_push() с упорядочиванием при высокой интенсивности concurrent запросов (с учетом pop (иначе будет бесконечно расти)). 

Не потребуется ли что-то порядка размер_списка \* число_push_потоков для вставки *одного* элемента?

Comment: Понял. Да, действительно, вижу годовалую работу [Lock-Free Red-Black Trees Using CAS](http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~hacamero/Research/RBTreesKim.pdf). Полистал, но пока не вникал. Было бы интересно использовать. Если деревья используются локально (вместо списка `local`), я только "за". Но на данном этапе хочу понять, на сколько оправдана такая оптимизация, и скорее всего вместо красно-черных буду использовать `AVL`, мне оно ближе.

Comment: @mega, наверное это я опять не до конца Вас понимаю. 

В ядре линукса деревья никак не связаны с концепцией lock-free. 

А какая **принципиальная** разница между `AVL` и красно-черными? Думаю для практики все равно.

Интересно другое. Когда можно (нужно) применять lock-free алгоритмы к достаточно сложным структурам? Видимо только в случаях, когда одновременный доступ маловероятен.