# Как `tail` попадает в `local`?

Tags: winapi, алгоритм, стек, lock-free, c++

Некоторое время назад я предлагал вводный [алгоритм для упорядоченного стека `lock-free`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/157092/c-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-lock-free) и теперь столкнулся с проблемой при его использовании: **адрес пограничного элемента списка (`tail`) периодически попадает в локальный список `local`**. Кто-нибудь может мне объяснить, с чем это связано?

Проблема [ABA](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_ABA) решена с помощью удвоения размера указателя (ABA'): младшая его часть - непосредственно на сам адрес узла, старшая - на его версию ( пока не выкладываю решение, чтобы не забивать мозг лишней информацией ). Надеюсь, проблема все таки в исходном алгоритме.

Разработка ведется на x64, т.е. для [CAS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) используется [`_InterlockedCompareExchange128`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/bb514094(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос пока снимается. Только что увидел ошибку: при неуспешном первом CAS'е нужно заменить `head` на `next`.

было:

```
// список пуст или `n <= head` - запоминаем локальный хвост, после `n`
next    = n->next;
// пытаемся атомарно разместить `n` на вершине стека,
// если она не изменилась
n->next = head;
if( _InterlockedCompareExchangePtr( &tail->next, n, head ) == head ){
    // получилось - удаляем `n` из `local`
    local.next  = next;
}else{
    // не получилось - восстанавливаем локальный хвост
    // и продолжаем lock-free итерации    
    n->next = head;
}
```

должно быть:

```
// список пуст или `n <= head` - запоминаем локальный хвост, после `n`
next    = n->next;
// пытаемся атомарно разместить `n` на вершине стека,
// если она не изменилась
n->next = head;
if( _InterlockedCompareExchangePtr( &tail->next, n, head ) == head ){
    // получилось - удаляем `n` из `local`
    local.next  = next;
}else{
    // не получилось - восстанавливаем локальный хвост
    // и продолжаем lock-free итерации    
    n->next = next; // !!!!
}
```

p.s.: в исходном алгоритме ошибку тоже исправил