# C++ асинхронный бесконечный цикл

Tags: c++, циклы, асинхронность

Здравствуйте. У меня есть бесконечный цикл. При запуске, как и ожидалось, программка виснет, ничего не нажимается. Как можно запустить этот цикл асинхронно?
В *C++* не очень силен, мне нужен простенький пример. Спасибо)

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < INFINITY; i++) {
    somefunction();
}
```

Comment: либо внутри цикла проверяйте пользовательский ввод, либо, что лучше, вынесите в отдельный поток. `std::thread` в помощь.

Comment: Немного почитал что такое потоки,  сейчас интересует, как  и где сохранить id потоков? А далее, как обратиться к потоку по id и закрыть его?

Comment: Это как минимум попахивает новым вопросом. Плюс, не забудьте уточнить стандарт с++ и какая библиотека для потоков

Comment: С++11. Стандартная библиотека `<thread>`

Comment: не нужно обращаться к потоку по id и пытаться его закрыть. Поток нужно попросить "завершиться", передав ему правильную переменную или другие примитивы.

Comment: окей, а как тогда попросить один поток(у меня их несколько) завершиться? и какую переменную ему передать?

Comment: Жмите кнопку "задать вопрос" и описывайте свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя `std::thread`, сделал бесконечный цикл внутри отдельного потока, которому можно передать в указатель  значение `false` и тогда цикл в потоку остановиться.

```
bool *ptrStatus = &status;
*ptrStatus = false;
```

Переменные `status` и `interval` имеют глобальную зону видимости.

Код:

```
bool status = true;
int interval = 1;

void startNewThread(int interval) {
    thread newThread(setWallpaper, &status, interval);
    newThread.detach();
};

int setWallpaper(bool *status, int interval) {
   while (true) {
      if (*status == false) return 0;
      wstring path = getPath();
      SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)path.c_str(), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(interval));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вынести функцию в отдельный поток `std::thread`, а вне этой функции управлять ею. Один из вариантов управления этой функции - через указатель. Вот небольшой пример где в бесконечном цикле выводится "some" до того момента пока мы не нажмем клавишу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void func(bool *workStatus)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < INFINITY; i++) {
        if (*workStatus == false)
            break;

        cout << "some "; // В вашем случае тут somefunction()
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool status = true;

    thread test(func, &status);

    while (!_kbhit());
    status = false;
    test.join();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: цикл будет бесконечный, так как значение переменной workStatus менятся не будет.

Comment: @KoVadim с чего такое утверждение ? запускали хоть ? я вот запустил данный код и цикл завершился при нажатии на клавишу - указатель же передается

Comment: В дебаге с под отладчика скорее всего будет работать. А вот в релизе обычно нет. Как минимум нужно добавить volatile. Но это ок для visual studio c++.

Comment: @KoVadim зачем тут нужен volatile. С релиза работает. Даже если компилятор залочит переменную во время проработки цикла while, это не скажется на проверке в потоке, мы же не меняем её значение. А зачем запрещать лочить переменную? Потом может получится так что пойдет считывание наполовину старого, наполовину нового значения, если в этот момент переменная будет менять значение. Может я где-то не прав, если да, то прошу узнать ваше мнение.

Comment: @Samilton volatile - это не про атомарность: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/165619/